# RADScheduler Appointments not appearing issue in Resource Grouping mode

Tags: binding, radscheduler

Hi i am using RAD Scheduler. The Problem is when i bind RAD Scheduler in Resource Grouping mode its not showing Appointments. If i remove resource grouping the scheduler is working fine.

I have two tables one for Projects (Appointments ) and other for Techs ( Resources.). Both table have FK relationship. I tried all possible way of binding ( In Memory DataTable with Custom fields required by Scheduler) and finally i m using Sql Data Sources for Projects ( Appointments) and Techs (Resources.) The FK relationship is defined.

And here is Resource defination

```
    <ResourceTypes>
            <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="sdsResources" ForeignKeyField="Assignedto" 
                KeyField="uID" Name="Tech" TextField="UserName" />
        </ResourceTypes>
```

here are two DataSources.

"

```
    SelectCommand="Select * From Techs" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsProjects" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Mycon %>" 
    SelectCommand="sched_GetSchedule" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="schedDate" Type="DateTime" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your scheduler markup there isn't a lot to go by, but I'll take a shot.

In your markup, you will need explicitely tell the scheduler how you want to show the grouping.

Between your `<telerik:RadScheduler>` and `</telerik:RadScheduler>` tags, include the following line:

```
<TimelineView UserSelectable="true" GroupBy="Tech" GroupingDirection="Vertical" />
```

You need to set the GroupBy property of your TimelineView tag equal to the Name property of the resource that you wish to group by.  In your example, the value is "Tech".
That will allow your grid to visually display the relationship.